# Enter key event not working on Numeric Input field?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, keyboard-events

I created two EditText with these two property.

```
android:digits="0123456789"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

I use Hardware Keyboard, when I perform Enter Key, focus control not shifting from one view to next view, as it happen normal in EditText case. If I remove "**android:digits**" property then it work properly, but here it allow to insert decimal key also, that I don't want.

I tried with "**android:nextFocusDown**" proerty also, but that is also not working in this case.

Any one have idea how can use Enter key event to shift focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

Either

```
android:inputType="number"
```

or

```
android:digits="0123456789"
```

**PS :**

best one is  `android:inputType="number"`  because it will automatically open the `numeric keyboard`

where as `android:digits="0123456789"` this will open `simple keyboard`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the layout:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

You don't need `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`, since you declared only digits in the `android:digits="0123456789"`

Comment: Thanks gOody, but then it allow me to insert decimal also...Tarsem answer work for me.