# Move to another EditText when Soft Keyboard Next is clicked on Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

When I press the 'Next', the focus on the User EditText must be move to the Password. Then, from Password, it must move to the right and so on. Can you help me on how to code it?

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User Name*" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_User"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password*" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_Password"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:password="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password*" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_Confirm"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:password="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Take a  look at android:imeOptions

Comment: where should I put that code?

Answer (score 525, accepted):

### Focus Handling

Focus movement is based on an algorithm which finds the nearest
neighbor in a given direction. In rare cases, the default algorithm may not match the intended behavior of the developer.

Change default behaviour of directional navigation by using following XML attributes:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/.."  
android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusRight="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusUp="@+id/.."
```

Besides directional navigation you can use tab navigation. For this you need to use

```
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/.."
```

To get a particular view to take focus, call

```
view.requestFocus()
```

To listen to certain changing focus events use a [`View.OnFocusChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html)

---

### Keyboard button

You can use [`android:imeOptions`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) for handling that extra button on your keyboard.

> Additional features you can enable in an IME associated with an editor
>   to improve the integration with your application. The constants here
>   correspond to those defined by imeOptions.

The constants of imeOptions includes a variety of actions and flags, see the link above for their values.

**Value example**

[ActionNext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_ACTION_NEXT) :

> the action key performs a "next" operation, taking the user to the
>   next field that will accept text.

[ActionDone](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html#IME_MASK_ACTION) :

> the action key performs a "done" operation, typically meaning there is nothing more to input and the IME will be closed.

**Code example:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to listen to imeoptions events use a [`TextView.OnEditorActionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html).

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            performSearch();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

Comment: In my case `android:nextFocusForward="@+id/.."` did the trick.

Comment: I put `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` to all my EditTexts and the problem is gone. Lot of thanks.

Comment: I had to use both joaquin and Mr.Moustard's for each EditText.

Comment: For my app, just using android:imeOptions="actionNext" didn't work.  The EditText needed android:inputType="[something]" before it would listen to the imeOptions flag.

Comment: agree with you @ChrisKelly

Comment: How does it know which one to focus when pressing NEXT ? Does it check the "right" and then the "down" ? Is there a function to get the next view's id to be focused, if the user would press the NEXT key ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper When pressing NEXT, the focus goes to down. You can set the next view id by, `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/NextFocusItem"`.

Comment: @SameeraNandasiri What about when there is a focusable view on the right? and, is there a function to get the next view's id to be focused, if the user would press the NEXT key ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Even if the view is on the right, you need to set it as nextFocusDown in order to focus changed by pressing NEXT. Its behavior is, focus go down when pressing NEXT. So by manually changing nextFocusDown parameter, we can override that behavior. It may be not the right way. But it works!

Comment: @SameeraNandasiri I see. But what about the other question I asked: is there a function to get the next view's id to be focused, if the user would press the NEXT key ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, You can get the next view's id to be focused by `<editText1>.getNextFocusDownId();`

Comment: @SameeraNandasiri What would happen if the other EditText doesn't have ID, or if it has an ID, but we just didn't set the attribute of "android:nextFocusDown" ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper In that case, I don't know a method to do it. If I wanted that functionality, I would set nextFocusDown attribute. I would like to know if there is a way to get Next Focus when nextFocusDown is not set.

Comment: That was the question. How to get the next view that will get the focus... Anyway, thank you.

Comment: This works if the field type is EditText. I was using AutocompleteTextView, there it didn't work, later on I had to change field type to EditText to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: i used same for next focus but issue with EditText with password inputType ,when i press next button from keyboard focus goes to passwordToggle(hide and show) eye  icon. what to do for focus next edittext instead of that eye icon.

Answer (score 71):

```
android:inputType="text"
```

should bring the same effect. After hiting next to bring the focus to the next element.

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/.."
```

use this in **addition** if you dont want the next view to get the focus

Answer (score 39):

**add your editText**

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:singleLine="true"
```

**add property to activity in manifest**

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

**in layout file ScrollView set as root or parent layout all ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ukuya.marketplace.activity.SignInActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <!--your items-->

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**if you do not want every time it adds, create style:
add style in values/style.xml**

default/style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.CustomEditText</item>
    </style>

<style name="AppTheme.CustomEditText"     parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
        //...
        <item name="android:imeOptions">actionNext</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Use of `android:singleLine="true"` is depricated.

Answer (score 24):

Use the following line

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/parentedit"
```

`parentedit` is the ID of the next `EditText` to be focused.

The above line will also need the following line.

```
android:inputType="text"
```

**or**

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Thanks for the suggestion @Alexei Khlebnikov.

Comment: It worked for me. Together with `android:inputType="text"` or `android:inputType="number"`.

Comment: if nextFocusDown won't work, then use nextFocusForward. It helped me

Comment: android:nextFocusDown="@+id/parentedit" worked for me! thanks

Answer (score 13):

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:singleLine="true"
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/.."
```

Adding extra field

> android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

worked in my case!

Answer (score 9):

In your onEditorAction handler, keep in mind that you must return a boolean that indicates if you are handling the action (true) or if you applied some logic and want the normal behaviour (false), as in the following example:

```
EditText te = ...
te.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            // Some logic here.
            return true; // Focus will do whatever you put in the logic.
        }
        return false;  // Focus will change according to the actionId
    }
});
```

I found this when I returned true after performing my logic since focus did not move.

Comment: If you return "true" from if condition focus will not change after your custom logic.

Answer (score 9):

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
                android:hint="@string/username"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:singleLine="true" />
```

These three lines do the magic

```
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 8):

In Kotlin I have used Bellow like..

1. xml:

   ```
   <EditText
     android:id="@+id/et_amount"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:imeOptions="actionNext"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:singleLine="true" />
   ```
2. in kotlin:

   ```
   et_amount.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->

       if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
           // do some code
           true
       } else {
           false
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Try Using **android:imeOptions="actionNext"** tag for every editText in the View it will automatically focus to the next edittext when you click on Next of the softKeyboard.

Answer (score 5):

just use the following code it will work fine and use inputType for every edittext and the next button will appear in keyboard.

```
android:inputType="text" or android:inputType="number" etc
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple way, when you have just few fields one by one:

Need to set

`android:maxLines="1"`

`android:imeOptions="actionNext"`

`android:inputType=""`
 **<-** Set your type of text, in other case it will be Multiline and prevent to go next

**Sample:**

```
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="@dimen/text_large"
              android:maxLines="1"
              android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
              android:imeOptions="actionNext"
              android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/element_margin_large"
              android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/element_margin_large"
              android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

In some cases you may need to move the focus to the next field manually :

```
focusSearch(FOCUS_DOWN).requestFocus();
```

You might need this if, for example, you have a text field that opens a date picker on click, and you want the focus to automatically move to the next input field once a date is selected by the user and the picker closes. There's no way to handle this in XML, it has to be done programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Add inputType to edittext and on enter it will go the next edittext

```
android:inputType="text"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

and many more.

> inputType=textMultiLine does not go to the next edittext on enter

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="666dp"
android:background="#1500FFe5"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editGrWt"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="6"
    android:text="    Diamond :"
    android:textColor="@color/background_material_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editDWt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editGrWt"
    android:background="@color/bright_foreground_inverse_material_light"
    android:ems="4"
    android:hint="Weight"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/editDRate"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"

    />
 <requestFocus />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="6"
    android:text="    Diamond :"
    android:textColor="@color/background_material_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editDWt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editDWt"
    android:background="@color/bright_foreground_inverse_material_light"
    android:ems="4"
    android:hint="Weight"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="0"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
 <requestFocus />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editDWt1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="6"
    android:text="         Stone :"
    android:textColor="@color/background_material_dark"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editStWt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView04"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editDWt1"
    android:background="@color/bright_foreground_inverse_material_light"
    android:ems="4"
    android:hint="Weight"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/editStRate1"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
 <requestFocus />
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/TextView05"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView04"
     android:layout_below="@+id/editStRate1"
     android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
     android:ems="6"
     android:text="         Stone :"
     android:textColor="@color/background_material_dark"
     android:textSize="15sp" />


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You might want to put an explanation with your answer to explain why your's is better than the others. You can press the "edit" button to add to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a multiline `EditText` with `imeOptions`, try:

```
android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way :

- Auto move cursor to next edittext
- If edittext is last input -> hidden keyboard

Add this to edittext field in .xml file

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Inside Edittext just arrange like this


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editStWt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" //now its going to rightside/next field automatically
    ..........
    .......

</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the element in scroll view then you can also solve this issue as :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:nextFocusDown="@id/ed_confirmPassword" />
```

and in your activity:

```
edPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                focusOnView(scroll,edConfirmPassword);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

public void focusOnView(ScrollView scrollView, EditText viewToScrollTo){
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, viewToScrollTo.getBottom());
            viewToScrollTo.requestFocus();
        }
    });
}
```