# Skipping disabled EditText's when pressing Next IME button on soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a `LinearLayout` with several `EditText`'s, all of them created programmatically (not with an XML layout), and in particular without IDs.

When I'm typing in one of the `EditText`'s, and the next one (respective to focus) is disabled, and I press the Next IME button on the keyboard, the focus advances to the disabled `EditText`, but I can't type anything in it.

What I was expecting was focus to advance to the next *enabled* `EditText`. I also tried, in addition to making the `EditText` disabled via `edittext.setEnabled(false)`, to disable its focusability via `edittext.setFocusable(false)` and `edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(false)`, and to set a `TYPE_NULL` input type, but to no avail.

Any hints?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move to another EditText when Soft Keyboard Next is clicked on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved by examining how the next focusable is found by the keyboard from [this blog post](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) and by subclassing `EditText`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View focusSearch(int direction) {
        View v = super.focusSearch(direction);
        if (v != null) {
            if (v.isEnabled()) {
                return v;
            } else {
                // keep searching
                return v.focusSearch(direction);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

More details:

`ViewGroup` implementation of `focusSearch()` uses a [FocusFinder](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/FocusFinder.java), which invokes `addFocusables()`. The `ViewGroup`'s implementation tests for visibility, while the `View` implementation tests for focusability. Neither test for the enabled state, which is why I added this test to `MyEditText` above.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it setting the focusable property to false, not only the enabled property:

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
editText.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: It's quite interesting, that it didn't work for me when I set the focusable property in layout XML, I had to do that in code to make it work. (ImageButton inside my custom compound view)

Answer (score 0):

See

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
            sendMessage();
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

This was grabbed from http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Action .

If you can figure out how to focus on the next `TextView`, you can add an `OnEditorActionListener` to every `TextView` and have it pass the focus to the next one if it is disabled.

Comment: Finding the next EditText is the point here. Since the EditText's in my activity are dynamic (their number and state is decided at runtime), I'd prefer not to keep a list of EditText's. How does the keyboard find the next EditText? Maybe looking into its source code may prove helpful...