# how to move the cursor from edittext to another horizontally when I press next?

Tags: android, android-edittext

When i click next it does not go all way round but it goes down?

Screenshot links below.

I have tried all types of  Layouts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to add android:imeOptions="actionNext" to your edit texts
and if it not helps you - try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17990096/2010395

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the next focus attribute for Focus Handling

[Focus Handling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

nextFocusDown
 nextFocusLeft
 nextFocusRight
 nextFocusUp

[check this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-the-basics-of-control-focus-order--mobile-8013)

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/your_next_edittext_id"
```

on your `EditText`'s.