# OnClick for Android "arrow" button on EditText keyboard

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I've searched and searched and I can't seem to catch a press on the "arrow" key on the android EditText keyboard. For me, it's the button right underneath the backspace that looks like an arrow.

I have tried using:

```
            @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {


            System.out.println(actionId);

            if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
                return false;
            }

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                System.out.println("keyCode == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION");

                trialNumber++;
                trialNumberTextView.setText("Trial" + Integer.toString(trialNumber));

                return true;
            }

            System.out.println("false");

            return false;
        }

    });
```

**EditText:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/sack_edit_text"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:hint="@string/trial_hint"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789."
    android:maxLength="2"/>
```

But nothing is printed out at all when I click the arrow button. This works for the digits on the keyboard however. I have tried changing the arrow button to a Done button in the EditText xml, but that doesn't work either. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1):

In your layout, just set the XML attributes `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`. You need to give your edittext single line true in xml.

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

and catch the next action on keyboard like:

```
 some_edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                some_button.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Also check [This So post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android) for a detailed description about softkeyboard actions.

Comment: There is still nothing happening when I click the next button now.

Comment: @Brejuro what exactly are you trying to achieve with this.I just wanna clear what's your reason so that i may help better.

Comment: I want to be able to do a set of things once a user hits the arrow button on the keyboard. Like on `onClick` for the arrow button.

Comment: @Brejuro you want your edittext to be multiline or single line?

Comment: @Brejuro check the new answer.

Comment: It's giving me the same error that I commented above :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95514/discussion-between-brejuro-and-anirudh-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` to your EditText in XML.

Next, set `OnEditorActionListener` on youe edittext like this,

```
etSack.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            ...your code...

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
              System.out.println("keyCode == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION");

              trialNumber++; 
              trialNumberTextView.setText("Trial" +        Integer.toString(trialNumber));

              return true; 
            } 

            System.out.println("false");
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: Now I got this message `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.KeyEvent.getAction()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Please see the update code. Use `actionId` instead of the event object.

Comment: Have you removed the use of `event` object completely? also, have you added the `imeOptions` tag in your xml?