# requesting focus of another EditText behaves in abnormal ways

Tags: java, android

I have four `EditText`'s to read a PIN. Now that I have coded the Java side of the `EditText` it behaves in an abnormal way. After entering one digit in the first `EditText` it should request focus of the second `EditText`, however it goes to the third `EditText`.

[image]

And even more it is defined as `numberPassword` and still the digits are visible.

Here is the source code to the layout file :

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mpin_1"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mpin_2"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mpin_1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mpin_3"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mpin_2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mpin_4"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mpin_3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The source code to the java file:

```
    public class SpinActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private StringBuilder s_pin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spin);
        s_pin = new StringBuilder();
        s_pin.setLength(0);

        Button sPinButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.set_s_pin_button);

        final EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mpin_1);
        final EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mpin_2);
        final EditText e3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mpin_3);
        final EditText e4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mpin_4);

        e1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(e1.getText().length()==1)
                    s_pin.append(e1.getText().toString());
                //e1.setEnabled(false);
                e2.requestFocus();
                return false;
            }
        });

        e2.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(e2.getText().length()==1)
                    s_pin.append(e2.getText().toString());
                //e2.setEnabled(false);
                e3.requestFocus();
                return false;
            }
        });

        e3.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(e3.getText().length()==1)
                    s_pin.append(e3.getText().toString());
                //e3.setEnabled(false);
                e4.requestFocus();
                return false;
            }
        });

        e4.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(e4.getText().length()==1)
                    s_pin.append(e4.getText().toString());
               // e4.setEnabled(false);
                return false;
            }
        });

        sPinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s_pin.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });



    }


}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edittext"
```

`edittext` is the ID of the `EditText` to be focused.

Comment: @shaheen Was this answer useful to you?