# Android - Next button not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have 2 fragments in the stack, both of them contain EditTexts.
(The red EditTexts is from the bottom fragment)

When I click the soft keyboard 'next' button, the cursor should move to the 2nd edit text, but instead, it's jump to the bottom fragment EditText.

If I use 'fragmentManager.replace(new TopFragment())',so there is only 1 fragment in the stack, there is no problem, and cursor move to the 2nd EditText.

'fragmentManager.replace(...)' is not a solution, I have a callback for the bottom fragment.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question, I cant understand anything.

Comment: question is really unclear. Not able to understand anything !

Comment: what is 1? 2? 3?

Comment: foreground fragment EditTexts. the red one is from the background fragment

Comment: Manually set the next focus fields as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to catch the enter press in the first EditText and `requestFocus()` by either using an interface to talk between the fragments or export the second's fragment's EditText variable (which I won't recommend)

example:

```
yourEditTextFragment1.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL
                && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // User pressed enter tell fragment 2 to requestFocus()
                // on it's EditText :)
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great! i added nextEditText.requestFocus() to this snippet. and it forces the focus for the expected editText

Comment: Make sure to check that the other fragment is present as they can be used in other places around the application...

Comment: @itzhar happy I helped, can you set my msg as the answer? ;)

Comment: @MaTriXy is right, before you focus check that the fragment actually exists.