# Android: Enter key move to next EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an anctivity with 6 EditText... the activity is working good, but I need to click on each EditText to fill it...

How can I make enter key change the focus to another EditText?

**What I've already tried**

**1**. I already setted OnKeyListener on every EditText.

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.editText1:
        activity.findViewById(R.id.editText2).requestFocus();
        return true;
    case R.id.editText2:
        activity.findViewById(R.id.editText3).requestFocus();
        return true;
    case R.id.editText3:
        activity.findViewById(R.id.editText4).requestFocus();
        return true;
            .
            .
            .
}
```

But, when I click on enter key, before the focus change to another EditText, a new line is create on previous EditText.

**2**. I've add `android:singleLine="true"` to every EditText. It isn't work on EditText with `inputType="number"`

Comment: Could you please try adding "android:maxLines="1"" too? in my experience there's difference having both of them even if one is "deprecated".
I think your option 1 is the way to go in this case.

Comment: You could also try with "setOnEditorActionListener(...", in the KeyEvent param listen for event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER and return true when this condition is true, that should stop EditText to do hes default behaviour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move to another EditText when Soft Keyboard Next is clicked on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android)

Comment: ~Tassadar: Setting maxLines="1" a new line is created, but edittext isn't resized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `imeOptions` attribute for `EditText's` in your xml:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

But not forget to specify `inputType`:
For example, `android:inputType="text"`

For more details check this question - [Move to another EditText when Soft Keyboard Next is clicked on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

**it working fine in otp screen i am using four edit text in this activity follow these step**

- i am using TextWatcher class like this

  ```
  /*Textwatcher class*/
  public class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
  private View view;
  public GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
  this.view = view;
  }

   @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  String text = editable.toString();
  switch(view.getId()) {
      case R.id.edit_otp1:
          if(text.length()==1)
              edit_otp2.requestFocus();
          break;
      case R.id.edit_otp2:
          if(text.length()==1)
              edit_otp3.requestFocus();
          break;
      case R.id.edit_otp3:
          if(text.length()==1)
              edit_otp4.requestFocus();
          break;
      case R.id.edit_otp4:
          break;
     }
    }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
   }
  ```

**Use textwatcher in edittext otp activity like this**

```
/*call textwatcher class*/
    edit_otp1.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(edit_otp1));
    edit_otp2.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(edit_otp2));
    edit_otp3.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(edit_otp3));
    edit_otp4.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(edit_otp4));
```

it works for me please try.