# focus is not shifting to next edittext automatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add and remove edittext through RecyclerView Adapter and it's working fine but I also want to shift the focus to next empty edittext when I click on adapter item which fills the edit text. It would be grateful if someone could help ,I am newbie to android.

1. Here is my focus next method:

```
private void focusNext() {
        View view = getAdapterView(mAddDropPointAdapter.getCurrentFocusedPosition() + 1);
        }
        if (view != null) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_google_autoc_et_destination).requestFocus();
        } else if (getActivity() != null) {
            KeyboardUtils.hideKeyboard(getActivity());
        }
    }
```

2. Here is from where I am calling this method.

```
@Override
    public void onAdapterItemClick(int position, @NonNull GoogleAutoCompleteAddressDto addressDto) {

/// Doing some stuff

 focusNext();
}
```

After clicking the adapter item , focus stays at the same edittext it doesn't shift to next.

Comment: is it multiline edittext?

Comment: No , it's single line edit text .

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android

Comment: Thanks @lvl4fi4, but it's not helpful as I don't have id of next edit text as it's adding dynamically.

Comment: `View viewItem = recycleView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
   EditText next = viewItem.findViewById(R.id.edittext);` and call requestfocus on it

Comment: this is what I am already doing   @Nullable
    private View getAdapterView(int position) {
        if (vRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
            return vRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
        }
        return null;
    }