# How to handle keyboard navigation and fabButton or bottomNavigationBar with long list

Tags: android, accessibility

On Android you can navigate through an activity using a keyboard's Tab key. What if you have a long list on the top and at the bottom a bottom bar/Tabs or the FabButton, currently in my project (perhaps also Gmail) you must scroll to the end of the long list before the items at the bottom can get focus, is this really how this works or is there maybe a recommended (better) way of handling this? 
There are impaired person that rely on using a device thorugh the keyboard, it should be really annoying to need to go through maybe 100 list items before you can get to the bottom elements below the list.

Comment: bottom bar stays fixed at the bottom of the screen, not to bottom of the list

Comment: There is a set of attributes which could help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android

Comment: @Vivek Mishra I know, but it won't anyways get focus still you scrolled through the whole list above.