# How does Android softkeyboard 'Next' work?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

Here is the basic design:

1. Each row is the item of adapter
2. Each row(item) contain three `EditText`

Here is the issue:

1. Click the top `EditText` which marked with RED box.
2. Click the softkeyboard `Next` button,
3. The next row can get the focus.(RED1 --> RED2 -->...-> REDn)

---

1. Click the top `EditText which marked with GREEN box,
2. Click the softkeyboard `Next` botton,
3. The next row `EditText` get the focus which means the focus (GREEN1--> RED2-->RED3-->...->REDn)

```
RED1  GREEN1
RED2  GREEN2
RED3  GREEN3
RED4  GREEN4
RED5  GREEN5
```

### My Question is:

1. RED1 --> RED2 -->... --> REDn.
2. GREEN1--> GREEN2 --> ... --> GREENn

### Here is the layout

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/drn3N.png]

Comment: Your question is not clear.
You want to know how to detect keyboard next button click or how to manage these focuses?

Comment: You can tell each layout element what the "next" element is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android